# Phonegap - How to call one javascript function in another file from index page?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am an iOS and PhoneGap newbie. I have the index.html file and a javascript file called MyClass.js.

In my MyClass.js, I have a function -

```
var MyClass = {

testfunc: function() {
    navigator.notification.alert("Success : \r\n");
}

}
```

I am trying to call it from the index.html function like -

```
MyClass.testfunc();
```

In my Phonegap.plist file I have an entry MyClass-Myclass as a key-value pair with the type String. However I don't get the alert. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get in logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the following in your index.html:

```
<script src="MyClass.js"></script>
```

This will allow you to use the MyClass.js functions in your index.html file

Comment: I did that but still unable to call an external function :(

Answer (score 1):

Your markup for your alert is wrong...

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Some Alert Text here', // alert message
    successCallback, // callback function
    'Alert Title, // alert title
    'OK' // button text
);
```

Comment: not really. just "Success : \r\n" should work too. It works when I put it in the index.html file inside the script tag.

Comment: i am calling it in onDeviceReady()

Comment: super strange. what order are you loading your js file? before or after your phonegap js?

Comment: what do you mean load? i specify <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script> before my own file

Comment: thats exactly what I mean, very strange. Sometimes the order in which you have your scripts loaded in will effect them, but you're doing it right. I am not entirely sure... do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try following code:

```
// MyClass.js
var MyClass = {
    testFunction: function() {
        alert("hi there");
    }
};

// index.html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="MyClass.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            navigator.notification.alert("hi there \r\n");
            //alert("hi there \r\n");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```